# Qt: how to make help system?

Tags: qt

I need to provide some help system for my application. The app mostly works on the computers without any Qt installed. I would like to have some way (tool etc) to create the professionally looking help system. I mean I need to provide the regular help system like most applications have. It should look like regular CHM file (with index, search etc.).

I tried to use QtAssistance class, created .adb file but if I run assistance utility, it doesn't know -profile key so I even cannot check if I did this file properly.

I'm a little bit confused because I could see QtAssistant and QHelp classes and I don't know which one is more suitable for my purpose.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Downvoter, I agree with the downvote, but please give @Seacat a clue as to why the downvote.

Comment: I don't understand, please explain what you don't like. The question is absolutely clear.

Comment: This is a very broad question, like asking "How do I build a house?" Also you ask which is more suitable for your purpose, but we know almost nothing about your purpose or application. We just need more information, and probably a much smaller scope for the question.

Comment: You don't need know about my app. It's been written in Qt, and I need to provide the help system. For example on .net  I could use HTML workshop to generate html and then HelpProvider component to embed this one into the app. I would like to do the same but for Qt. I could see there are 2 classes: QtAssistant and Qhelp, which one is more suitable for this goal? If you every use them you should know. I'm pretty new in Qt that's why I don't know and ask.

Comment: So, what you're asking is, `What are some of the major differences between QtAssistant and Qhelp in terms of ease of generating quality help files?`. If that's your question, I'd re-post. This one is getting no response. It's too broad and vague.

Comment: Hmmm... my question is which system do I need to use to provide the professionally looking help system (like chm) that could be embedded into Qt app and provided on the system without Qt installed? Is it clear now?

Comment: No, that's like asking "What car should I buy?" Some people will say one is better, others will say the other is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not care for using Microsofts chm-files, then go ahead and use the QtHelp API - if you are using Qt versions 4.4 or newer. The QAssistant API has been superseded by QtHelp starting with version 4.4, so don't start with old or deprecated interfaces. The QAssistant help files will still be readable from a QtHelp based implementation.

If you do need to read chm files, then a chmlib-based approach with a customized QWebBrowser would be suitable, but I don't think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, now I understand... I didn't know about the fact that QtHelp superseded QAssistant. Probably it explains why it's so difficult to find details on this topic. Thanks!